# Loss of connection when connected via switch

Tags: ubuntu, router, switch, connection

we've currently set up 7 ubuntu machines connected to a switch and that switch to a router-modem, router has dchp configured to bind each machines specific Mac address to an ip (in essence static IP for each machine)

The problem is, all 7 machines would simultaneously fail to connect to the network, as in all within the same minute. Upon further checking on site, we found that anything currently plugged in to the switch will not have e network connectivity, but anything connected to the router will, we tested by plugging one machine directly to the router and the rest to the switch and true enough, all will go down except that one, we can still access the monitor and keyboard but nothing we do will restore connection, we have tested with a laptop and plugging it in, no connection established as well

We thought it is a faulty switch so we have replaced it 3 times with 2 different brands even, cables also have been replaced a few times with both cat5 and cat6, we have also used 2 switches at the same time out of 2 of the 4 router ports and ALL failed at the same time

So the question is, what could be the possible issues? Router acting up? Wiring? Ubuntu issue?

*Edit, it seems to only be sending but nothing is being received back, attempting to set a static IP on the laptop or using dchp does not work either*

Thanks!

Comment: The symptoms sure sounded like something that could have been explained by a faulty switch. But given how many times you have replaced the switch, that is probably not it. I would verify a few things. Can the machines connected to the switch still communicate with each other? Are there any possibility that something else on the network is claiming to own the MAC or IP address of the router? Maybe the port on the router is defective, have you tried a different port?

Comment: Not sure, it happens sometimes in a few hours, sometimes in a day, my thinking is that if it works immediately it should continue to work all the way..

Comment: In fact we connected two out of the router to a switch and a router that has dchp turned off, went down. After 26 hours

Answer (score 1):

Is the port you're connecting the switch to on the router configured to be a trunk port (opposed to an access port)?  that may explain why the port would drop if it saw a switch with multiple MAC addresses connected to it.

Basic definitions of switch and trunk ports I've pulled off the Cisco forums:

There are two types of switchports: trunk or access.

A access port is typically for a switch to host connection and this port is assigned to only one VLAN.

A trunk is typically a link between two switches or a switch and a router.  This allows multiple VLANs to traverse the interface/link.

Comment: Not sure if it is.. I'm using a ZTE f609 if that helps.. will try to source for another router, problem is it needs to have a optical port in

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if your hosts miss internet connectivity or full network connectivity.
Are they able to ping each other?

However I would proceed this way:

1. check the switch leds: anything unusual?
2. disconnect all the 7 clients from the switch and then reconnect them one by one, to make sure that the cause is not some faulty NIC on one of the hosts.
3. disconnect the switch from the router and check if the hosts are able to ping each other

I would focus my attention on the lower network layers: MAC addressing (is something messing up the switch?) and physical NICS.

Check the cable connecting the switch to the router and make sure that ethernet Speed/Duplex is set up correctly (you might need to force it to something different from "auto negotiation").

Comment: The machines cannot ping each other totally, it's not internet loss rather total loss, did a test that day to plug in a cable from the switch to a laptop in it's downed state and it cannot work also

Comment: But after remove the cable from the switch and plugging in to the laptop, it works immediately, plugging it back into the switch makes it fail again, but if I power off all machines and restart each one by one it will work again one by one till all are restored

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Px2016, full loss or partial loss of network connectivity? I would bet the the machines could still ping each other. You say the switch is connected to a router-modem. Is this a cable modem? If so, check if in full or partial bridge  mode.

What happens if you provide a machine on the switch with static IP, DNS and Gateway address? Can you still ping other machines while losing connectivity to modem? If so, problem is most likely with modem (or its setup).

Comment: I think it's total loss, can't ping gateway and each other when it is down, can try to manually set a static IP the next time I happens but not sure if it would solve the issue

Comment: Am thinking it is caused by cloning of the machines so when it tries to do something network wide it affects everything else and confused the whole network

Comment: It may not solve, but is absolutely a troubleshooting step. Take every step to determine exactly where communication is first being dropped and then work out from that. If you are working with clones, verify unique MAC addresses for your NICs.

Comment: Ok, will set a static IP for each machine when I go on site next time, when it occurs again, will try to do a oing test.. ifconfig shows a different Mac address for each

Comment: also be sure to set the correct subnet mask for your environment.